# expand one column/div, while moving other columns around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dashboard

I am creating a sample dashboard UI, which has 3 columns/divs with 3 cards or tiles in each column. On click, I am expanding each card using jQuery animations,  and the cards/tiles in the same column do move down when the selected one expands. However the elements in other columns do not move, and cards end up overlapping each other. How can I move the other cards from different columns around when expanding one of them? (For now, just the top left card has animation attached to it)

codepen - http://codepen.io/arjun2523/pen/bdXrPB

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>3 column tiles</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "column-left"; overflow:auto>
      <div class = "card-blue expand" id = "blue-column-1"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-green"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-pink"></div>
    </div>

    <div class = "column-center">
      <div class = "card-blue"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-green" id="green-column-2"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-pink"></div>
    </div>

    <div class = "column-right">
      <div class = "card-blue"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-green"></div>
      <br>
      <div class = "card-pink"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.expand {
  height: 500px;
  width : 500px;
  position: relative;

}
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}

.column-center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.card-blue {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#blue-column-1 {
  position:relative;

}

.card-green {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px
}

.card-pink {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightpink;
  padding: 10px
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#blue-column-1").click(function(){
  var blue = $("#blue-column-1");
  blue.animate({height:'500px', width:'500px'}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: What do you want the widths of the other columns to be after the click?

Comment: maybe use the horizontal layout and set display block for div that you are clicking

Comment: I have some quick questions. 1. Do you want the columns to have equal width (currently 33%) after clicking? 2. Do you also want to expand other cards of the same column?

Comment: @BryanHill - other columns should remain the same width. Just their positioning is to be affected when one card is clicked, to move out of the way of the expanded card.

Comment: @Patrice - same width for the columns. and only one card which is clicked should expand. other cards in the same column remain same size

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem you should first change the width of the column div, not the card div. Then once you get that set all of the widths to percentages instead of px (that will just make sure it will never have overflow). Then when you use the JS change every column width. Ex: 33% 33% 33% -> 49% 25% 25%. Then everything should work if the card divs are set as percentages.

Comment: If you give me the percentages you want ill give you a sample code.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer to include some example code instead of just explaining the steps?